# How to insert its next sibling element in between its two children?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a situation like below:

```
<body>    
    <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</body>
```

The `table` is not within the `form` but as a sibling. However, I would like to place it between two input elements which are in the `form`. Since the table size is variable, I cannot directly assign a fixed value to the `top` style of `submit`. Instead, the position of `submit` has to be according to (i.e. several px below) the end of `table`.

Comment: You would need Javascript to do that. CSS cannot affect order of elements that do not share a parent.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have discovered a way to do that with CSS only, which is as follows:

HTML

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>table data 1</td>
                <td>table data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>table data 1</td>
                <td>table data 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
input {
  display: block;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

table {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check code.

html

```
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>table data 1</td>
        <td>table data 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

css

```
input[type="submit"] {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

or you can visit given url also - https://codepen.io/piyushjn/pen/eqyXaM

Let me know if you need anything.

Comment: I do not wish to put the `table` inside the `form`.(I'm not the downvoter though)

Comment: I have updated code according to your requirement. please check this url - https://codepen.io/piyushjn/pen/RXxOLa

`position` is the only solution which I can see here.

Comment: In your solution, `table` is still inside the `form`. But anyway thanks for your answer. I do have got help from it for finding the solution I finally got.